# Fixed header and slide down content

Tags: html, css

I'm running into trouble with this. I have a sticky header with a text box that when clicked slides down a results box and pushes the content down. It works ok when the header is positioned on top. The problem is when I scroll down the content and I click on the search text box and my results box is no longer visible. Here is the example: http://www.neolamanite.com/sites/all/themes/jquery/test.html

For some add reason the client wants a sticky header but doesn't want the results box to go over the content. He wants the results box to push it down. Any ideas? Can this be fixed with jQuery

Here is how the html looks like:

```
<div class="sticky-header group">
  <div class="sticky-header-inner">
 <input type="text" class="text default-value" value="click here to open results" style="width: 300px;">
 </div>
</div><!-- sticky header -->
<div id="search-autosuggest">
 <ul>
   <li>Result 1</li>
   <li>Result 2 </li>
   <li>Result 3 </li>
   <li>Result 4</li>
 </ul>
</div><!-- search-autosuggest -->
<div id="sticky-wrapper">
 .... content here
</div>
```

Here is the example: http://www.neolamanite.com/sites/all/themes/jquery/test.html

Works when there is no scrolling down. Not when scrolled down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this css to your `#search-autosuggest` container:

```
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -500px; /* Half the container's width */
```

**Edited after feedback:**

Sure it can be done with jQuery :) I'd do it by 'faking' the pushing down effect. Anyway, the effect doesn't really makes sense. You'll see it better watching it in action. Add the above styles to the `#search-autosuggest` container and use this js:

```
$('.sticky-header input.text').click(function () {
    if ($("#search-autosuggest").is(":visible")) {
        $("#sticky-wrapper").animate({
            marginTop: '-=267'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    } else {
        $("#sticky-wrapper").animate({
            marginTop: '+=267'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
    $("#search-autosuggest").slideToggle();
});
```

As you can see, the content is pushed down as desired, but... You can't see the the beginning of it if you have scrolled down. If you tell me what your desired behavior is, i'll try to fix that (e.g. if you want the scroll to be on top if the input text is clicked, easy peasy).

**EDIT:**

To make the window scroll to the top when the users clicks the input, you need to add `window.scrollTo(0,0);` at the end of the `else` block. If you want the transition to be smooth, you can add this: `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);` instead of the above code.

Comment: This would work but my client wants the content to be pushed down by the toggling box and not go over the content. I know it is a crazy request. Just wondering is there was a jQuery solution to it.

Comment: Thanks Scumah. This is great! Would you mind showing me how to do it so that the beginning is visible. Specially when you've scrolled down and trigger the event. thnks

Answer (score 0):

**The Fix**

Basically, your header is position fixed. But your results box is not...

Just add `positioned:fixed; top:45px` to `#search-autosuggest` in your css (line 29)

**Why it works**

`positioned:fixed` tells the browser that the element should be positioned relative to the current window (ignoring scrolling). So because the bar is positioned fixed and top 0 px. It is placed at the top o the current window.

Meanwhile the results box is not, so it is positioned at the top (WITH SCROLLING) meaning that you can scroll past it. By adding positioned fixed you position the bar realtive to the window. Additionally the `top:45px` lowers the resuls by 45 pixels (so it is just below the header (which is 45px tall)).

Comment: This would work but my client wants the content to be pushed down by the toggling box and not go over the content. I know it is a crazy request. Just wondering is there was a jQuery solution to it.